# efficient org-mode table data entry

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I am building a table that I add a few rows to each day.  Many times, I need to add an entry that is identical to an entry higher up in the same column.  Often, in fact, there is a row higher up that is identical to the row I need to add except for a couple of fields (which may themselves occur higher up in their respective columns, just in different rows).  Also, each row has a higher expected resemblance to the row that immediately precedes it than to rows that are higher up.  Any tips for speeding up data entry here?  So far all I have tried is copying an entire row and then modifying it and using dynamic abbreviations, but neither of these works very well.  On a side note, Emacs's dynamic abbreviation facility seems very clumsy. It does not even recognize, for instance, email addresses.  And the functionality to add additional words using "space M-/" does not seem to work properly. Am I perhaps using it wrong, or is there an alternative?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. If there's no set rule for determining which parts of which rows you want to duplicate, I don't think you can program Emacs to do it for you. Maybe an example would help?

Comment: A simple example of helpful functionality would be a way to autocomplete a field, where the set of possible autocompletions would be the set of entries in the column that the field belongs to.  Another example: if one column lists names and another email addresses, after inputting the name (maybe using autocompletion), emacs might guess that the email address might be the one that has always before been associated with that name and make that email address easy to enter.

Comment: You may find this post inspiring, where Sacha Chua uses the Insidious DB inside org-mode, but I can't help you more. http://sachachua.com/blog/2008/12/emacs-org-and-bbdb-hyperlinking-names-to-blogs/